# Silex "hello world" - 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, silex

I have LAMP on fedora 21, install silex, created a virtualhost. It is config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName film.dev
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/video/web/
</VirtualHost>
```

In the /web directory I create .htaccess with content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options-MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /video/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

On page http://film.dev/hello, I got a 404.

In file web/index.php I changed: 
"$app->get('/hello'," to "$app->get('/',"
It's work.

Tell me, how can I solve the problem with the redirect?

Comment: Comment your RewriteBase line, it's not needed as you're in the docroot, not some levels below.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options-MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /video/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

With

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /video/web
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your vhost configuration info below .

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName film.dev
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/video/web
<Directory "/var/www/html/video/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All 
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Hope this can help you!